# Multiple if statements to define what filters are applied and ignored in R

Tags: r, if-statement, filter

I've searched various posts related to this question and still cannot find a solution.

I'm trying to apply multiple filters on a dataframe that involve if() statements that if a condition is met then it includes the individual filter inside {} in the set of filters, and if the statement is not met then it ignores that particular filter.  Consider the follow base code that works perfectly although it doesn't include the if statements yet.

```
library(tidyverse)
llibrary(purrr)
library(dplyr)

Cb1 <- 0.75
Cb2 <- 1.0
Cb3 <- 20
Cb4 <- 8

test <- map(metrics, ~filter(., 
                             industry == "Technology",
                             price <= (median(price, na.rm = TRUE)) * Cb1,
                             ror >= (median(ror, na.rm = TRUE)) * Cb2,
                             debt <= Cb3,
                             periods >= Cb4,
                             price >= 0))
```

The code references a list of 3 dataframes titled "metrics" that I'm not including in the code for simplicity (which means that you won't be able to test this code).  But it includes numerous columns of data, some of which include: industry, price, debt, periods, and ror.  Which are the columns that I'm interested in filtering.  Note that this includes a map function because it is performing the filtering on the 3 dataframes included in the list "metrics", but that is not important in my question.

I would like to add some if statements that check if the constants Cb are not equal to 0, then the filters inside {} are included in the set of multiple filters.  But if the constants Cb are equal to 0, then this particular filter is excluded in the multiple set of filters (and the other filters still may apply).  Through some research I thought that maybe using "else" after the {} and simply having nothing after "else" will achieve what I'm looking for.  But it does not work.  This is the code that I've tried using if statements inside the filter function, but again this does not work.  To clarify, the code runs without errors, but the filters do not work properly.

```
Cb1 <- 0.75
Cb2 <- 0
Cb3 <- 20
Cb4 <- 8

test <- map(metrics, ~filter(., 
                                industry == "Technology",
                                if(Cb1 != 0) {price <= (median(price, na.rm = TRUE)) * Cb1} else
                                if(Cb2 != 0) {ror >= (median(ror, na.rm = TRUE)) * Cb2} else
                                if(Cb3 != 0) {debt <= Cb3} else
                                if(Cb4 != 0) {periods >= Cb4} else
                                price >= 0))
```

I feel like this something relatively simple like the syntax of where I place my {}, (), or even the commas.  Or maybe it's some combination of boolean operators (& or |).  But I can't seem to get it to work. Note that there are also some filters that don't include an if check as I want them to always apply.

I would normally try to include an expected outcome, but that is difficult since this is a set of filters on a dataframe that I cannot include.  I'm hoping that someone can help with my syntax in the if statement code and that will solve the problem.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `filter()` function expects each of its inputs to be a logical vector, equal in length to the number of rows of the data frame, or 1. "Excluding" the filter might mean the filter always resolves to `TRUE`, leaving all rows in place.

So you could change your statement to this (note the comma at the end):

```
if (Cb1 != 0) { price <= (median(price, na.rm = TRUE)) * Cb1 } else TRUE,
```

I have a comment though: What you are doing here feels a bit counter-intuitive. Perhaps if you could describe better *why* you are trying to do this, there might be a more dplyr-like solution.

Comment: After I've tested several possible combinations, this is working!  Thanks so much!  I thought it might be something simple.  Yes, I realize it feels a bit odd to have the if statement check if a value is (or is not) 0.  What I'm looking for is the filter to ignore one specific line of filtering if a constant is 0 so if I put this portion of code in a larger map function in which the constant Cb1 varies from 0 to 3 in increments of 1, it will ignore a specific filter in the cases where Cb1 is zero.  I hope that helps clarify.  But again, thank you!

Comment: Glad to be of help! By counter-intuitive, I meant I am not used to seeing control flows inside filter calls, but maybe that's just me.

Comment: Perhaps there is a better way to achieve my objective.  Maybe filter_if or filter_all, or some other function I'm not thinking of?  I'm somewhat new to R, so that is entirely possible.